# How did Dr Frankenstein get enough plus size parts to make his oversized creation?

Tags: origins, frankensteins-monster, mary-shelley

Mary Shelley's Doctor Frankenstein was forced to make his creation larger than a normal man in order to be able to surgically reassemble the body parts he obtained by robbing local cemeteries. How was Victor Frankenstein able to get enough plus size body parts to make his 8 ft 2 in monster when the graveyards were likely full of average size dead people?

Comment: I don't remember the protagonist killing extra big and tall villagers...

Comment: I don't remember the original book using corpses for the material.

Comment: This made me think about the comment in Frankenstein Junior about the various effects of having assembled an enormous body...;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The book doesn't make it clear exactly how Frankenstein created his being. Decades of films have left us with the impression that it was built from whole parts, a leg here, and arm there, and presumably whole organs, but if anything the book suggests the creature was built from smaller bits. For example Frankenstain says:

> I collected bones from charnel-houses and disturbed, with profane fingers, the tremendous secrets of the human frame.

If he was starting with bones presumably he wasn't just stitching together whole body parts, and in that case he could have constructed limbs any size he wanted. There's also the statement:

> The dissecting room and the slaughter-house furnished many of my materials

where the mention of the slaughterhouse suggests that maybe not all the parts came from human bodies.

Comment: Sounds like I should grab one of the original books - only seen movie adaptions so far. But this also explains something that's never explained in the movies: If he's able to reanimate a creature made from several body parts, why doesn't he keep the body intact, saving all that trouble of putting it together again?

Comment: "What I cannot create, I do not understand." - Richard Feynman https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman